# Python Django url reverse in unittest returns a 404

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

url:

```
path('some/path_to/<int:special_id>/', some_views.someAPI.as_view(), name="someAPI")
```

Normally when accessing the API with `https://some_domain/some/path_to/1`, I can get the data with `special_id=1`. No issue here.

However, when I run a test which contains the `reverse()` function, the `special_id` doesn't seem to be loaded.

I'm doing

```
url = reverse('someAPI', kwargs={'special_id': 1})
request = self.factory.get(url)
force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)
response = someAPI.as_view()(request, special_id=1)
```

it gave me a 404: Not found when I expect a 200

I checked the path, and it seems to be correct. I'm wondering why I'm receiving a 404. This is running through django unittest.

EDIT:

Turns out I didn't save the object in the test db. Make sure you call `save()` when creating object.....

Comment: Make sure your instance in the testing DB has `ID==1`, sometimes the `ID` is not generated as you expect.

Comment: Good point. I'll try printing out all the records and examine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During a test a new database called "test_dbname" is created and flushed immediately. You have to create the element with id: 1 before the reverse() function.

Comment: yea.... this is it..... I created the object but didn't `save()`........

Answer (score 0):

And what if you do:

`reverse('someAPI', args=[1]`

Comment: same thing. I start feeling it's my database's issue. I can't find any problem with the code itself. Gonna check that as well